# Center ul in container

Tags: html, css

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/dpynebnf/

Super simple, I'm just trying to center the ul in it's conatiner.

I don't want to use text-align: center; becasue I still want the text left aligned but I want the whole block centered

```
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-12 col">


                    <ul>

                        <li>
                            <h3>Sone Title</h3>
                            <p>Some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
                        </li>


                        <li>
                            <h3>Sone Title</h3>
                            <p>Some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
                        </li>


                        <li>
                            <h3>Sone Title</h3>
                            <p>Some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
                        </li>


                        <li>
                            <h3>Sone Title</h3>
                            <p>Some text some text some text some text some text some text </p>
                        </li>


                    </ul>

                </div>

            <!--<div class="col-sm-1"></div>-->

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: I dont get your point really. If you use `text-align: center` on the col, and `text-align: left` on the ul, it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave there `text-align: center` and overwrite that in child element using `text-align: left`:

```
.col {
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0  auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dpynebnf/3/

OR

maybe you´re looking for `display: table`

```
ul {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: white;
    display: table;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0  auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dpynebnf/1/

Comment: I would rather avoid the use for `display:table;` unless you were displaying tabular data (which *should* be the only time to use anything to do with tables).

Comment: I added there second option. And display: table is valid for this task, don´t be worry :-) I changed order of those options, first is with text-align and as the second with display: table. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `text-align: center;`. You just have to re-align the UL text to the left:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dpynebnf/2/)

```
.col{
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
ul{
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0  auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it. You just need to add text-align left to your `ul`
http://jsfiddle.net/dpynebnf/5/

Answer (score 1):

I (hope) you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/dpynebnf/6/)

This is using the `text-align: center;` property on the whole list and overrides the `li` using `text-align: left;`.

```css
.col {
  background: blue;
  //text-align: center;

}
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12 col">


      <ul>

        <li>
          <h3>Sone Title</h3>
          <p>Some text some text some text some text some text some text</p>
        </li>


        <li>
          <h3>Sone Title</h3>
          <p>Some text some text some text some text some text some text</p>
        </li>


        <li>
          <h3>Sone Title</h3>
          <p>Some text some text some text some text some text some text</p>
        </li>


        <li>
          <h3>Sone Title</h3>
          <p>Some text some text some text some text some text some text</p>
        </li>


      </ul>

    </div>

    <!--<div class="col-sm-1"></div>-->

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ul{
border: 1px solid red;
color: white;
list-style: none;
margin: 0  auto;
width:500px;
}
```

try this one .it will also work with out add any new html element